# How to get deployment to go back to the amount of pods under replicas in the deployment yaml

Tags: kubernetes

created a simple deployment with just 4 pods. I increased this to 8 using the kubectl scale command.

After a restart of the app the pods are still at 8. Is there a way when restarting a deployment to get it to read the deployment yaml(and in this case deploy 4 pods) or override the amount of pods set by the kubectl scale command?

Comment: two questions, ***1st***, how do you increase the replica count to 8? ***2nd question***, how do you restart the app?

Answer (score 0):

You re-apply YAML and update the config of deployment with **replicas:4**, YAML apply config will override your config and update the replicas to 4.

**Or**

you can rerun the scale command again to scale to **4**

Comment: But still new deployment config will get applied it will override config of edit.

Comment: if that answers your question feel free to update the status of the question, and mark it as answer of do upvote if found it helpful. that's how SO works.